# блок div меняет свою высоту, относительно рядом стоящего

Tags: css, html, height

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется такой блок, но почему-то , там где единичка, высота блока не изменяется, я специально убрал там высоту но проблема не решилась.

Это совершенно два разных блока, которые идут друг за другом.

Нужно, чтобы автоматически блок с цифрой, занимал всю высоту открытого блока.

ВОТ так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CODE:

```js
function show(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  if (div.style.display == 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
    toggler.innerHTML = '+';

  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
    toggler.innerHTML = '-';
  }
}
```

```css
.FunctionalBlock {
  width: 1170px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.FunctionalBlock .Numeric {
  width: 100px;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: #dadada;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.FunctionalBlock .MainDesc {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 101px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.FunctionalBlock .HideDesk {
  display: none;
}

.FunctionalBlock .OpenClose {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="FunctionalBlock">
  <div class="Numeric">1</div>
  <div class="MainDesc">
    Decription
    <a class="OpenClose" onclick="show('Decription');">+</a>
    <div class="HideDesk" id="Decription">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the pirnting and typesetting inclustry
      <img src="preview/img/">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И как мы вам поможем? Добавьте код.

Comment: Я добавил код!!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Div Блоки одинаковой высоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539051/div-%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: [Как сделать три блока одинаковой высоты в CSS с отступами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448862/191745)

Comment: пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь пользоваться поиском на сайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `float` и `align-content` у селектора `.FunctionalBlock .Numeric`, а родителю, т.е. `.FunctionalBlock`, задайте `display: flex;`. И не пишите названия классов с большой буквы :)